# Java - Inheritance from class in different project

Tags: java, maven

I am pretty sure, that this topic has been discussed somewhere else already. I just don't know what to look for.

I have a bigger Java project built by Maven. It has some modules which are Maven projects as well. I need to create new module, where I have to inherit from some classes defined in the parent project.

Is there a way to build only my module?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to declare a dependency on other project. As long as the JAR for that is installed in your Maven repo, you can build just your own module (and use the binary from the other one).

Comment: You can just define your parent module dependency in your module pom and you will be able to build your module. Hope this help you.

Comment: You shouldn't have projects which contain code as parent projects. Parent projects should just be POM-packaged. What you need for this new project is declare the other project as its **dependency**, not its parent.